# Confusion in usage of synchronized keyword

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, monitors

This is confusion while preparing for an exam, I have weird piece of code that does nothing except bugging my head. Refer the below code

```
public class p2 implements Runnable {

    static Object lock = new Object();

    public void run() {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        synchronized(lock) {
            System.out.println(name + " entering lock.");
            try { lock.wait(); } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
            System.out.println(name + " came out");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new p2()).start();
        new Thread(new p2()).start();
    }
}
```

The output of the code is :

```
Thread-0 entering lock.
Thread-1 entering lock.
```

My question is when the thread enters the synchronized block it has exclusive access for that block, since it has ownership on that object's monitor. Then why `Thread-1` is allowed to enter the monitor?

Comment: The quote block (prefixed by `>`) is not for emphasis, it is for **quotes** from other sources.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation for Object.wait()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ok it says that the current thread leaves the monitor and waits for another to notify it. Thanks for pointing